# Hover on div to trigger another div

Tags: html, css

This is what i have so far. What i would like to do is that when i hover on the div `book1`, I want the div `uploadbutton` to be shown. I cant seem to figure it out.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #uploadbutton {
   display:none;
  }
</style>
```

This is my div and the above one is my css style

```
<div id="book1">
<?php include 'viewing_display_pic.php'; ?>
</div>

<div id="uploadbutton">
<?php include 'upload.php'; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**adjacent sibling selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

```css
#uploadbutton {
  display: none;
}
#book1:hover + #uploadbutton {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="book1">
  some random text
</div>

<div id="uploadbutton">
  some random text
</div>
```

> The adjacent sibling combinator is made of the "plus sign" (U+002B, +)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   immediately precedes the element represented by the second one.

Comment: @Kunz Glad that I helped you. Please don't forget to mark it as correct when you can to help future searches :)